# gps based alarm

Tags: android, gps

I want to develop an Android app that alerts the user at specific recognized locations using gps tracking, firstly we recognize some specific areas, when the user approaches this area he has to be given an alarm, please help me to get the tutorial starting from the basics, since I am a beginner.

Comment: Please be aware that having the GPS turned on always will drain the phone's battery quite quickly

Comment: Is GPS accuracy necessary, or would the coarse location (from wifi) be okay?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`LocationManager.addProximityAlert`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
    i think you have to require following steps like
    [1] google md5 certificate for your map
    see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey
    [2] make gps location listenr service in your project
    see http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-location-based-services.html
    [3] also Create AlaramService which notify the location and Alert using Brodcase Receiver
       here do require code for AlaramService
    [4] Add Require Permission and service register  in Manifest 
      like 
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>  
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"></uses-permission>  
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"> </uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
this some steps which may useful to you
```